# NullPointerException while setting a value to Textview passed from previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

```
Intent i = getIntent();
categorie_label = i.getStringExtra("categorie_label");
TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.catid);
txtrank.setText(categorie_label);
```

Why the code below returning a `NullPointerException` ? Please help

Comment: Post the log, the code where you put the string extra and the layout XML.

Comment: the  categorie_label  return a value "PIZZA" so is not null but the eror start in txtrank.setText(categorie_label);

Comment: txtrank  return null!!!

Comment: can you please post your xml code ?

Comment: <TextView
                android:id="@+id/catid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:text="Date of Birth: July 3, 1962" />

Comment: Are you calling setContentView()?

Comment: your categorie_label must be null

Comment: how you pass "categorie_label" ?

Comment: resultp = data.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Entite.class);
    Log.e("---eded--", String.valueOf(resultp));
    intent.putExtra("categorie_label",
    resultp.get(Magasiner.categorie_label));

Comment: this code is from the categorieadapter when i click into the grid colone

Comment: @med
You should inflate XML in your new activity or create View (in your case it's a TextView) programmatically

Comment: i don't understand you @Semyon can you be more clear please

Comment: @med of course. I suppose you have XML which describes layout for your activity. It has a TextView with id 'catid'. This layout must be inflated in your activity container. In Activity::onCreate call
`setContentView(R.layout.name_of_your_layout_file)`

Comment: ok i will try this thanks and i will answer you

Comment: ok , it was my fault the cat_id was inside another list view so it was impossible to set categorie_id in this list but i use other solution by getting the categorie_id directly from my json and thank you a lot for your help @Semyon

Answer (score 0):

Your activity probably did not find the TextView with the specified ID in it´s layout and thus it is null. You should check if it is contained in that layout.